# Trigger signal when add relation to model

Tags: django, django-models

Given the following model, with four instances already created (A, B, C, D) I want to trigger a hook when I add a Company to the instance D.

```
    class Foo(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField()
        description = models.TextField()
        company = models.ManyToManyField(Company)
```

I've thought about using a post_save signal but I'm not sure if it's a good approach.

Comment: My mistake, I updated my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, my bad. I misunderstand your question. In cases where your want to handle the save of a `m2m` field the best practice is to use the [`m2m_changed`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#m2m-changed) signal.

In general, using signals is a good practice. That's one of the reasons they are created for!

```
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Foo.company.through)
def handler(sender, instance, pk_set, action, **kwargs):
    if instance.name == 'D' and action == 'post_add' and instance.company is not None:
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using builtin pre-save signal. This way you can fetch D instance and check if 'company' field is about to change. Then add a hook.

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Foo)
def foo_pre_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    try:
        foo = Foo.objects.get(name=D_name)
        if((foo.company == None) and (instance.company != None)):
            # do your hook here
    except Foo.DoesNotExist:
        # handle exception
```